# How to figure out if there is an actual horizontal tangent without a graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

There is this practice problem that asks to determine the points at which the graph of $y^4=y^2-x^2$ has a horizontal tangent.

So I did implicit differentiation to find that

$$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{2y^3-y}$$

To find the horizontal tangent, I set $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and solved for $x$:

$$\begin{align}
\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx} &= 0 \\
\frac{-x}{2y^3-y} &= 0 \\
-x &= 0 \\
x &= 0
\end{align}$$

Then I substituted $x=0$ into the equation of the curve:

$$\begin{align}
y^4&=y^2-(0)^2 \\
0 &= y^4 - y^2\\
0 &= y^2(y+1)(y-1) \\
y&=-1,\,0,\,1
\end{align}$$

I concluded that the points $(0,0)$, $(0,-1)$, and $(0,1)$ were the points with a horizontal tangent.

However, when I graphed this using Desmos, it turns out that the point at $(0,0)$ did not look like it has horizontal tangent.

[Graph of y^4=y^2-x^2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PjKa.png)

How would I have been able to figure this out *without* graphing it?

Comment: At $y = 0$ derivative is not defined! Simply look at your expression for derivative for that.

Comment: Ah! did not even consider that.

Comment: A fraction is $0$ where the numerator is $0$ and the denominator is NOT $0. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the answers is $(0,0)$. 
However, at this point, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ attains $\frac{0}{0}$ form. 
So, I think you should not consider the  point $(0,0)$.

Comment: Why should it not be considered? Once it is ascertained that the numerator and denominator are both $0,$ there is more work to do to find out whether there is a horizontal tangent there.

Answer (score 0):

If
$y^4=y^2-x^2
$,
then
diffing implicitly,
$4y^3y'
=2yy'-2x
$
or
$2y^3y'
=yy'-x
$.

If $y' = 0$,
then
$x = 0$.

Putting this in,
$y^4 = y^2$
so the possible values are
$y = 0, \pm 1$.

At $x=y=0$,
suppose $y' = c$.
For small $x$ and $y$,
$y \approx cx$
so
$c^4x^4 \approx c^2x^2-x^2$
or,
dividing by $x^2$,
$c^4 x^2 \approx c^2-1$.
Since
$c^4x^2$ is small,
$c^2-1$ must also be small
so
$c^2 \approx 1$
so
$c \approx \pm 1$.

This means that,
at $(0, 0)$,
$y' = \pm 1$.